# Cloudformation condition on parameter in Role policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I am creating iam role and its managed policy. In managed policy I want to give allow access to invoke API(Gateway). This template is going to execute on at least 6 environments I want to use condition based approach to assign API gateway url in resource so that template will be easy to maintain and execute.

Based on type of environment API url is going to change.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: >-
  This template creates Role and policy
Parameters:
  envname:
    Type: String
    Description: Enter envname
    AllowedValues: 
      - dev
      - dev2
      - sit
      - uat
      - prf
      - prod
  prodaccountid:
    Type: String
    Description: Enter Prod AccountID
Resources:
  DeviceRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      RoleName: 'DeviceRole'
      MaxSessionDuration : 43200
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS: !Join ["",[!Sub 'arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/',!Ref envname,'_Role']]
              Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS: !Sub 'arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:user/test-user'
              Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'              
  DevicePolicy:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy'
    Properties:
      Description: >-
        This Policy will be attached to the device role
      ManagedPolicyName: !Join
                      - ''
                      - - 'DeviceConnectPolicy'                        
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:          
          - Effect: Allow
            Action: 'execute-api:Invoke'
            **Resource:
              - !Join ["", [!Sub 'arn:aws:execute-api:${AWS::Region}:',!Ref prodaccountid,':aaaaaaaaaa/Test/PUT']]
              - !Join ["", [!Sub 'arn:aws:execute-api:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:bbbbbbbbbb/*/PUT/*/*/*/v2']]
              - !Join ["", [!Sub 'arn:aws:execute-api:${AWS::Region}:',!Ref prodaccountid,':cccccccccc/*/PUT/v2/s']]
              - !Join ["", [!Sub 'arn:aws:execute-api:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:dddddddddd/*/PUT/*/*/*/v2']]**
       Roles:
        - Ref: DeviceRole
```

I want to use conditions in Resource.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please format your code ?

Comment: Formatted please have a look

Comment: what kind of condition do you want to use? Can you explain that?

Comment: Hi. I've noticed that you have a number of questions and most of them have answers provided. However, you have not accepted any of them. It is a good practice to accepted good answers as it helps others with same/similar problems. If useful answers are not accepted, it prompts people to make duplicate question on a false assumption that existing answers to your questions are not helpful.